# Delete a location from time machine

Tags: time-machine, macos

I have a folder in `~/Downloads/Media` with lot of media files backed up in time machine. Since I moved the files back and forth it has taken so much space in my external drive. Can anyone tell me a way to remove the location from `Time Machine` completely? I want to remove the location permanently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open System Prefs > Time Machine, then click Options…
You can add exclusions to the list, by clicking the + & navigating to the location, or simply by dragging any folder/drive etc into the box.

[image]

It would appear that anything already backed up will stay in the older backups until eventually it just 'falls off' over time, as Time Machine cycles through your drive space.

Comment: would that delete old capsules of the folder?

Comment: I'm not sure. They'll either be removed at next backup, or just gradually fall off as the backups get older. Either way, the space will free up.

Comment: Cool, I just did it.

Comment: Ah… just checked - they will fall off over time. I still have an old backup of something I excluded recently. It's gone from newer backups but is still there in older ones. I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: My disk is almost full, I gues it will fall off with the time. (y)